# Loopback - Easiest way to extend a built-in model

Tags: node.js, inheritance, orm, loopbackjs

I've been using Loopback to create an API. The documentation is generally really good but doesn't really answer my question about the following: how do I **extend** (not replace) a built in model?

The most promising piece of information came from [this page](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Extending+built-in+models) - it specifies the way of basing a class from another class, via inheritance. This is useful but not ideal - I'd like to create relationships to custom models from the stock models, for example - "Role" should have many "Permission".

The page I mention also shows a Javascript file, located at `common/models/<modelName>.js`, where it states you can "extend" a model based on the properties and options you give it. The server never seems to hit the file... For example - I put a file in `common/models/role.js` with the following content:

```
var properties = {
  exampleProperty: {type: String, required: true}
};


var user = loopback.Model.extend('Role', properties);
console.log('test');
```

First off, it doesn't seem to hit the file at all (no `console.log` output given). Second, obviously because of the first point, it doesn't extend the model with the properties I created.

Am I missing something obvious or is the documentation just plain wrong?

Comment: same problem here. docs seem rather incomplete when explaining how to extend builtin models - they seem to suggest u can extend, but like u, i found that using for example, user.json/.js isn't an option. did u try inheritance as suggested here? i'm concerned it will break access tokens or generally cause more problems.

Comment: Hi there, yes inheritance is the way to go. If you extend the base `User` class you will receive the same methods and somehow it figures out the accessToken stuff for you too.

Answer (score 5):

You should generate a new model via `slc loopback:model` named `user`. By default, the built in user is named `User`, which is why you can use lowercase `user` or even `UserModel` if you prefer. Then when you are prompted by the model generator for a base model, choose `User`. See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-faq-user-management/blob/master/common/models/user.json#L3

Comment: Thanks, I guess the documentation is a bit misleading. I wanted to add new properties and relations to the original models, but I guess this isn't the best way.

Comment: Yes, extending the built-in model and then adding your properties and relations is definitely the way to go.